# Exclude category from DB query

Tags: post-meta, wpdb, exclude

I have next code:

```
$drivers_all = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'driver'")
```

With this one I get the values of all fields “driver”. How can I exclude some category in this code?

Comment: Do you really want to hard-code 'Driver' in there? There must be a better way to do this using the standard search. But to continue your SQL example you should `AND NOT EXISTS` a sub-query that matches the `wp_postmeta` `post_id` against `wp_term_relationships`, then using `wp_terms` and `wp_term_taxonomy` to find the taxonomy ID for your category. But you ought to do this properly with the standard query objects, not hard-code `wp_` as the table prefix, etc. - this isn't the answer.

Comment: I need to count all unique values of “driver” except one category. By this time I’ve found only this part of solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better approach, but this query should do what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta pm
  WHERE meta_key = 'Driver'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wp_term_relationships tr
                      JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
                      JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
                    WHERE pm.post_id = tr.object_id
                      AND tt.taxonomy = 'category'
                      AND t.name = 'ExcludeMeCategory');
```

When translating this into php you should use the `$wpdb` aliases for table names, i.e. `$wpdb->postmeta`, `$wpdb->term_relationships`, `$wpdb->term_taxonomy`, `$wpdb->terms`. You should also probably profile this query to make sure it's executing in reasonable time and isn't doing full table scans, etc. - I don't a representative database handy to test it.

Finally I don't know taxonomies well: this may be incomplete w.r.t. e.g. taxonomy hierarchies, and it may be simpler / better to query the taxonomy ID first and then drop that into the query in place of `wp_terms_taxonomy` onwards in the query.